# IT-140 Project 2 Python

Tags: python, dictionary, scripting, key, traceback

I am working on my final project for my intro to scripting class. we are using python. my code seems to be doing well except a a few lines of code, i cannot seem to define my item and state. The errors are traceback errors on lines 27 and 45.
Here is my code:

```
# declaration
rooms = {
        'Town Square': {'North': 'Bookstore', 'South': 'Restaurant', 'East': 'Tailor', 'West': 'Jeweler'},
        'Tailor': {'East': ' Town Square', 'item': 'Suit'},
        'Restaurant': {'North': 'Town Square', 'East': 'Hair Dresser', 'item': 'salad'},
        'Hair Dresser': {'West': 'Restaurant', 'item': 'Comb'},
        'Book Store': {'South': 'Town Square', 'East': 'Shoemaker', 'item': 'Bible'},
        'Shoemaker': {'West': 'Book Store', 'item': 'Shoes'},
        'Jeweler': {'North': 'Chapel', 'West': 'Town Square', 'item': 'Ring'},
        'Chapel': {'South': 'Chapel', 'item': 'Wife'}
}
state = 'Town Square'


# function
def get_new_state(state, direction):
    new_state = state  # declaraing
    for i in rooms:  # loop
        if i == state:  # if
            if direction in rooms[i]:  # if
                new_state = rooms[i][direction]  # assigning new_state
    return new_state  # return


# function
def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['Item']  # returning Item value


# function
def show_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print("Welcome to the Wedding Adventure!")
    print("Collect all 6 items before you reach the chapel, so you will not die of embarrassment when you get left at "
          "the altar")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


show_instructions()  # calling function
inventory = []
while (1):  # gameplay loop
    print('You are in ', state)  # printing state
    print('Inventory:', inventory)  # printing inventory
    item = get_item(state)  # calling get_item function
    print('You see a', item)  # print
    print('------------------------------')
    if item == 'Wife':  # if
        print('SLAP ... GAME OVER!')
        print('Thanks for playing! Hope you enjoyed it!')
        exit(0)
    direction = input('Enter your move: ')  # asking user
    if (direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go South'):  # if
        direction = direction[3:]
        new_state = get_new_state(state, direction)  # calling function
        if new_state == state:  # if
            print('The room has wall in that direction enter other direction!')  # print
        else:
            state = new_state  # changing state value to new_state
    elif direction == str('get '+item):  # if
        if item in inventory:  # if item already present in inventory
            print('Item already taken go to another room!!')
        else:
            print(f"{item} retrieved!\n")
            inventory.append(item)  # appending
    else:
        print('Invalid direction!!')  # print
    if len(inventory) == 6:
        # print
        print('Congratulations! You have collected all items and got married!')
        print('Thanks for playing! Hope you enjoyed it!')
        exit(0)
```

The code runs but has traceback errors on when initially run. I am not certain on how to trace the inventory for the items. Should I create a new dictionary for inventory?

Comment: `Town Square` has no `item` but that is what you are using as the index

Comment: I noticed that! thank you for the mention. I noticed a few errors in my dictionary as well. the code runs and completes with the proper output with or without 6 items. Now i just have some tweaking i want to do to clean it up. Thanks for the help!